# Decode part literal bytes in str

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

I have a str like `"abc\\xe2\\x86\\x92"`, what I want is  `"abc→"`. (`b"abc\xe2\x86\x92".encode()` equals `→`)

The problem is, `\\xe2\\x86\\x92` is in `str`, and `\\` is just one character so there is no way to replace it into `\`.

Comment: Anything unclear about my question?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this:

```
In [107]: original.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
Out[107]: 'abc→'
```